# How to use assembly code you get online?

Tags: linux, assembly

I have some C code I would like to optimize. It turns out the Intel C Compiler (ICC) does a much better job at this than GCC but I don't have a copy of that compiler and it is very expensive. However, I can compile it using ICC and get the assembly online at [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/g/C9DxTH).

If I copy and paste this assembly into a text file, how can I then convert it into a functioning executable?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its an attempt to skirt licensing and may be illegal.

Comment: I don't think copying assembly for my own code is illegal is it?

Comment: @max "may be illegal" is not a reason for closing questions.  Knowledge is valuable for its own sake, and it cannot be presumed that the actions enabled by the knowledge will be carried out.  Especially since the knowledge in this case is how it ***cannot practically be done***.  (Also, It "may be" *insert-anything-here* is not a reason for closing questions to begin with.)  And no, it is not illegal, because she is not copying the compiler, she is copying one instance of output of the compiler.  Fair use.

Comment: @MikeNakis While I agree with you, the sentence "it is not illegal" is too strong and deceptive. Software law is complex. You can't play a movie in a square for everyone to watch for free, though nobody is copying anything. I'm pretty sure ICC license doesn't allow renting and either the OP or Matt Codebolt can get in trouble for that.

Comment: @MargaretBloom well, okay, let's put it this way: whether it is legal or not should be the subject of a question in http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I believe the particular ways, how the C was assembled, can be seen morally as "intellectual property" of Intel. Not sure how this could be done in law without making whole SW world pain (as it already is with SW patents), but at least from moral aspect I would advise the OP against this, and either look for g++ version with better output, or try to modify your C a bit to help it. And it's unclear to me *why*, the difference in performance is probably only couple of percent, and if you *need* such difference, and yet you don't know Assembly well enough to do it, then you should hire a pro.

Comment: BTW, if you can produce reasonably simple sample of the bottleneck routine, the stackexchange site codereview may be of help to you, to get that g++ output optimized "for free" (well, the cost is to prepare self-contained small-enough source, and then extracting the gained knowledge back into big project). Also you may expect sh*tstorm of advices how to do it in completely different more efficient way, which would require ~1 month of refactoring at least and the person suggesting it may be not correct in the end. :)) But hey, it's for free, and hiring a pro may end similarly, if unlucky.

Comment: As a student, you can get old versions of the Intel C compiler for free. Perhaps use that?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to begin by making sure that the runtime environment for which godbolt.org compiles is similar enough to your runtime environment, (good luck with that,) because for example you may be using windows, and godbolt.org may be using linux, (or the other way around,) so when you bring the assembly to your system you might be able to convert it to object code, but it will still not link and it will not run.

Then you will need to find an assembler for your platform which is compatible with the syntax of assembly produced by the intel C compiler of  godbolt.org so as to produce object files from the assembly files.  (Good luck with that.)

Then you will need to find any and all runtime libraries (redistributables) required by code produced by the intel C compiler. (Good luck with that.)

Finally you will need to obtain a linker to link your resulting object files with the runtime libraries to produce an executable.  (Good luck with that.)

Sometimes we need honest answers to our questions just so that we can realize how impossible our ideas are.

Comment: OP is talking about few routines of his own I suppose, so actually all they need is to simply copy the asm from godbolt, and adjust syntax for their assembler. Which makes me wonder why this Q even exists, if somebody lacks knowledge to do that, then he has to delve into his toolchain documentation to learn how to assemble assembly files together with rest of the project, and which assembler is used, or how to use alternative one (to minimize syntax adjustments). Also if one is not familiar with Assembly, this may be very error-prone effort, probably not worth the extra 1-5% of performance.

Comment: @Ped7g Well, that would be reasonable, that's what I thought too in the beginning, but in the last sentence she says "If I copy and paste this assembly into a text file, how can I then convert it into a functioning executable?" so this leads me to believe that she is actually thinking of obtaining all of the assembly code of an entire program in a single assembly file and producing an executable out of it.

Comment: Thank you. The issue in this particular case is vectorization which is much better in icc. I expect it to be at least twice as  fast. My system is linux which I am assuming is the same as theirs but I could be wrong.